# how to filter the venues from foursquare api using the price parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foursquare

```
$params = array(
            "ll" => "$lat,$lng",
            "llAcc" => "100000", //"100";
            "radius"=> "100000",
            "categoryId"=>"4d4b7105d754a06374d81259",
            "venuePhotos" => 1,
            "price" => $price,
            "sortByDistance" => 1,
            "limit" => $limit,
            "offset" => $offset,
            "intent" => "global"
```

);

```
$response = $this->foursquareapi->GetPublic("venues/explore",$params);
```

Is it possible to filter the venues using the price parameter or what is the other way??

Price parameter does not work for all the countries as per my experience. It works for venues from certain countries like united kingdom,austria,belgium,united states. But same time it does not work for the venues from the countries like Australia,India,etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the explore api endpoint price should be used as following:

> Comma separated list of price points. Currently the valid range of price points are [1,2,3,4], 1 being the least expensive, 4 being the most expensive. For food venues, in the United States, 1 is < $10 an entree, 2 is $10-$20 an entree, 3 is $20-$30 an entree, 4 is $30 an entree.

As such, if you are passing in the relevant values to your price key it should be returning filtered venues as appropriate

Comment: Yes, it is working for the united states, But if I try the same for India or Australia, I am not getting the output. So Is it country dependent???